# OnDisconnected does not fire with reloading the page

Tags: signalr

im using signalr-rc2 and use it for cross-domain long-polling calls on IIS7(not express)

everything works fine execpt OnDisconnected on server-side

when i hit the close button on browser(firefox or chrome) OnDisconnected invoked but

when i refresh the browser tab,,OnDisconnected does not invoked

however i test it on a small project an it works fine totally

my question is whats the diffrence between reloading browser page and closing it

i wait almost 15 minutes for delay of IIS to realize client disconnection but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was two html tag in document 
caused by asp.net mvc view render(i forgot to return partialview instead of view in action method)

Comment: you should probably delete this question